# Copying files between servers hidden behind VPNs

Tags: vpn, openvpn, scp

I am considering how to efficiently copy files (>500GB) from one machine to another (both machine are running Linux). The challenge here is that both machines are only available behind separate VPNs: one being OpenVPN (office1, which I would prefer leaving unchanged) and the other not yet determined (office2, outside of my control)

Normally, in order to ssh/scp/rsync to either of these machines, I would connect my laptop to the corresponding VPN, before using the local IP of the machines in the ssh/scp/rsync command:

```bash
ssh -i ~/.ssh/o1_username o1_username@192.168.50.4
scp -i ~/.ssh/o1_username whatever.file o1_username@192.168.50.4:~/
rsync -ae "ssh -i ~/.ssh/o1_username" --info=progress2 whatever.file o1_username@192.168.50.4:~/
```

However, I am stumped as to how to transfer a file from one of these machine to the other... Here are a few workarounds I can envision, but none are completely satisfying:

1. I have a raspberry pi in office2 running ngrok for global ssh access. I can use it as an ssh jump host to connect. This is inefficient since both ngrok and the pi can bottleneck the bandwidth:

```bash
ssh -i ~/.ssh/pi -t -p 12345 pi@0.tcp.ap.ngrok.io ssh -i ~/.ssh/o2_username -p 1022 o2_username@123.123.123.123
scp -r -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i ~/.ssh/pi -p 12345 pi@0.tcp.ap.ngrok.io -W 123.123.123.123:1022" -i ~/.ssh/o2_username whatever.file o2_username@123.123.123.123:~/
```

2. I could transfer the files in two steps, first copying them onto my laptop or a cloud drive, then onto the target machine. This seems a bit clumsy and should not be necessary given the VPNs are supposed to make connections easier
3. I had an [FRP setup for global ssh access](https://github.com/fatedier/frp#access-your-computer-in-lan-by-ssh) for the machine in office1, but I removed it when we set up the office1 VPN, thinking it would now be obsolete. I could set it back up and pipe the ssh/scp through it. I am however afraid that this solution will be bottle-necked by the FRP server I set up. I would also need to pay costs for network traffic through that connection, so I don't consider it a very sustainable high capacity solution.
4. I could maybe connect to the VPN in office1 using the machine in office2, but I haven't yet figured out how to connect the VPN using the Linux command line, and I am concerned about disturbing the internet connection for other users/applications on the machine in office2 (or vice versa)

How can I best leverage the available VPNs to transfer files between the 2 offices, without affecting the internet setup for other users and my own other running applications? It it even possible/reasonable?

(Usernames, port numbers and IPs obfuscated for security reasons)

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: if you want to copy files between two machines directly, they need to have a direct connection to each other. So, only the fourth option seems sensible. Whether that means you add one machine to the VPN of the other, or just have a third machine that's reachable from both machines and make a third "mini-VPN" just for these two, the effect is always the same: as long as you only set a route for the other machine to go through that VPN connection, you do not affect the routing for anything else.

If you do go the route of mini-VPN just for this purpose, I'd just get the cheapest VM you can find (Oracle's free VM tier is pretty awesome in bandwidth), and put a minimal wireguard setup on there – it's nice, it comes with current linux kernels (and is available for basically any OS, including mobile and commercial non-Unixes), needs no extra setup but enabling IP forwarding, and creation of three keys in total (which is running two command lines), and that's it. I *think* your frp does the same (never heard of it!), but less efficiently.